# how to creat a hyper link on images

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a hyperlink on images, but, when I add a tag,   images not showing. How to add hyperlink in this case?

```
<div class="content-block-01 margin-top-40">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="content-w">
                <div class="content-02 content-img">
                    <img class="ult-new-ib-img" style="opacity: 1;" alt="" src="/image/01.jpg">                    <div class="line-block-2"></div>
                    <div class="text-block">
                        <h2>text</h2>
                    </div>
                    <a class="link-block"></a>                                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please create fiddle or codepen to understand.

Comment: enclose the `<img>` in `<a>`

Comment: If you want to hyperlink an image, you need to wrap the img tag in an a tag <a href="/something"><img src="something.jpg"/></a>

Comment: <a href=""><img></a> is the default way. In your case, check if you have any css rule(s) that hides images inside <a> tag. Something like `a img{display none;}` or `a img {height:0;}`

Comment: @MCMXCII I did just like you mentioned, but after that images are disappearing.

Comment: @andrew thanks andrew, I will check that.

Comment: @liveinfootball also, after you put the <a> tag, check if your image is still in thesource code of your page. Perhaps there is javascript that removes/hides it after page load

Comment: If your image has disappeared when you've put it in an a tag, firstly make sure you've closed your a tag off correctly, then check that you have no css applicable to a tags, e.g. display none, a good tool for this is the inspector.

Comment: @andrew Thanks let me check it

Comment: @MCMXCII Thanks for your sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `img` tag should be wrapped within the `<a>` tag

```
<a class="link-block">
 <img class="ult-new-ib-img" style="opacity: 1;" alt="" src="/image/01.jpg">                    
 <div class="line-block-2"></div>
  <div class="text-block">
 <h2>text</h2>
 </div>
</a>
```

If your image is not visible, check whether you have a css style that hides it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what your looking for <3

```
<a href="http://www.yourlink.com">
<img alt="icon" src="log.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

*First*:

Enclose `<img>` in `<a>`:

```
<a class="link-block" href="www.example.com">
    <div class="content-02 content-img">
        <img class="ult-new-ib-img" style="opacity: 1;" alt="" src="/image/01.jpg">
        <div class="line-block-2"></div>
            <div class="text-block">
                <h2>text</h2>
            </div>                               
        </div> 
    </div>
</a>
```

*Second*:

Use JS on image itself:

```
 <img onClick="location.href='www.example.com'" src="/image/01.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Include image tag inside anchor tag then image will work as hyperlink.

Example:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Go to google" >
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help set image path in  tag and also set your href link in anchor tag:

```
<a href="Your link path" target="_blank">
<img src="Your Image Path" alt="PlayerSoft" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your effort. I am using a specific theme for ecommerce solution. I found that it was made to add an hyperlink in this area.

```
<a class="link-block" href="#"></a>
```